# test servlet using Junit

Tags: java, postgresql, junit

I just started learning Java, and I can't fully understand how to write Junit tests for my application. In the code below i implement the servlet function DoPost where do i add new people for my database.  In this example I am getting database connection through servlet context,
where did I put hikari pool connection at the beginning of the program.

```
   @Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException {
    try  {
        addPerson(request, response);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "one or more"
            + " parameter has invalid type");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "such person is already exists");
    }
}

private void addPerson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException, SQLException {
    connection = getConnection(request);

    response.setContentType(CONTEXT);

    PreparedStatement statement = getConnection(request).prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL);

    String role = extractParameter(request, PERSON_ROLE);


    statement.setString(1, extractParameter(request, PERSON_FIRST_NAME));
    statement.setString(2, extractParameter(request, PERSON_LAST_NAME));
    statement.setString(3, extractParameter(request, PERSON_CONTACT));
    statement.setString(4, extractParameter(request, PERSON_EMAIL));
    statement.setString(5, ValidateUser.validateRole(role));

    statement.executeUpdate();

    try (PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter()) {
        writer.print("<h2>person was added</h2>");
    }
}
public Connection getConnection(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (Connection) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("connection");
}
```

My test code for this/

```
    @Test
public void shouldReturnOneWhenPersonWasAdded() throws IOException, SQLException {
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    PersonServiceServlet servlet = mock(PersonServiceServlet.class);
    PreparedStatement statement = mock(PreparedStatement.class);


    Connection connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres", "postgres", "kharn");

    when(servlet.getConnection(request))
        .thenReturn(connection);



    when(request.getParameter(PERSON_FIRST_NAME)).thenReturn("Nick");
    when(request.getParameter(PERSON_LAST_NAME)).thenReturn("Vick");
    when(request.getParameter(PERSON_CONTACT)).thenReturn("90999900");
    when(request.getParameter(PERSON_EMAIL)).thenReturn("some@mail.com");
    when(request.getParameter(PERSON_ROLE)).thenReturn("teacher");

    when(statement.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(123);

    servlet.doPost(request, response);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
    when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

    assertTrue(writer.toString().contains("<h2>person was added</h2>"));

}
```

but this approach does not work, I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

You are currently mocking your system under test (servlet). You need to change this line:

```
PersonServiceServlet servlet = mock(PersonServiceServlet.class);
```

to

```
PersonServiceServlet servlet = spy(PersonServiceServlet.class);
```

Then you need to stub correctly. Change this:

```
when(servlet.getConnection(request))
    .thenReturn(connection);
```

to

```
doReturn(connection).when(servlet).getConnection(request);
```